# PHPExcel not able to read excel file downloaded from internet until I open the file and save it without making any change

Tags: phpexcel

I just started using PHPExcel yesterday. It works like a charm except when I use it to read xlsx file downloaded from internet. It is not able to read the file until I open the dowloaded file and save it explicitly without making any change.

```
   $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFile);
```

Line I use to load the Excel file. 
Where am I going wrong? Am I missing some code. Something else needs to be written along with the above line of code to load the file.

```
foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
    $worksheetTitle     = $worksheet->getTitle();
    $highestRow         = $worksheet->getHighestRow(); // e.g. 10
    $highestColumn      = $worksheet->getHighestColumn(); // e.g 'F'
    $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);
    for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; ++ $row) {
        for ($col = 0; $col < $highestColumnIndex; ++ $col) {
            $cell = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row);
            $val = $cell->getValue();
                if($col==0){
                        $val = \PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::toFormattedString($val, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
                }
            $dataArr[$row][$col] = $val;
        }
```

This code is able to read the excel when I open the excel and save it.

Comment: Impossible to tell... don't know what the file is that you're trying to read.... is it really an xlsx file? Or just a file with an extension of .xlsx? What does it contain that might break the file parser? Are there any errors? Does it load with corrpt data? etc

Comment: It is actually an xlsx file. There are no errors and it does not load with corrupt data. Once I open the excel on my computer and press ctrl+S(Save it, without making one single change), then the file is read without any problem.

Comment: I dont know if its a file with just an extension of xlsx. It opens fine in excel and is recognized as an excel when it is downloaded. So I think its a proper xlsx file.

Comment: A call to `PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify()` should at least check if PHPexcel recognises it as a genuine OfficeOpenXML xlsx file.... but this is still totally insufficient information to be able to help you in any way. What does it contain that might break the file parser? Are there any errors? Does it load with corrupt data?

Comment: There are no errors. It does not load with corrupt data. When I open the file and save it(without making any changes), the file gets uploaded and data is entered in the DB without any problem